# differences between "boxer", "trunk", and "brief"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What are the differences between "boxer", "trunk", and "brief"?

Here is the sentence:

> I'm not a fan of long boxers, I prefer trunks or briefs.

Answer (score 3):

These are various types of men's underwear.

The differences are to do with the length of the legs and the looseness of the fit.

- Boxer shorts are looser fitting and have longer legs.  (Like the
  shorts that boxers wore)
- Trunks are tighter and have shorter legs.
- Briefs are tight fitting and have no legs, just leg holes.

Comment: While I agree with the above point, there is a difference between boxer briefs and briefs. Briefs are exactly as the answer describes whereas boxer briefs have longer leg than trunks but are equally as tight, they also generally have a 3-panel system for comfort. There are a lot of men's underwear out there and I think it can get quite confusing.